# Update Embeded Google Trends

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, api

I have this function that loads a Google Trends graph. It works, but if I call it again with new data the graphs duplicate! How can I solve this?

```
loadGraph(div: HTMLElement, type: string) {
  trends.embed.renderExploreWidgetTo(div, type,
    {
        comparisonItem: this.keyWords,
        category: 0,
        property: ""
    },
    {
        exploreQuery: "geo=MX&q=chamarras%20de%20piel&date=today 12-m",
        guestPath:"https://trends.google.es:443/trends/embed/"
    });}
```

Data:

```
keyWords: any[] = [
{
    keyword: "some word",
    geo: "US",
    time:"today 12-m"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The renderExploreWidgetTo appendsa a Child to the HTMl element, so div.innerHTML = ''; solves it.